# Camera unable to detect multiple colours in python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get my camera to detect both red and green colours.
Now it can detect either one colour successfully, but it can't detect both colours.

```
ball_color=('red','green')
```

If I change it to *ball_color=('red')* or *ball_color=('green')* it can work, but when i put *ball_color=('red','green')* there's errors.

I added the error code at the bottom. Thanks alot!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


ball_color=('red','green')

color_dist = {'red': {'Lower': np.array([0, 60, 60]), 'Upper': np.array([10, 255, 255])},
             'green': {'Lower': np.array([35, 43, 35]), 'Upper': np.array([90, 255, 255])},
             }

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('camera', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while cap.isOpened():
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   if ret:
       if frame is not None:
           gs_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)                     # 高斯模糊
           hsv = cv2.cvtColor(gs_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)                 # 转化成HSV图像
           erode_hsv = cv2.erode(hsv, None, iterations=2)                   # 腐蚀 粗的变细
           inRange_hsv = cv2.inRange(erode_hsv, color_dist[ball_color]['Lower'], color_dist[ball_color]['Upper'])
           cnts = cv2.findContours(inRange_hsv.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

           c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
           rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
           box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
           cv2.drawContours(frame, [np.int0(box)], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)

           cv2.imshow('camera', frame)
           cv2.waitKey(1)
    

cap.release()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error code are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fangyaoting/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/顏色辨識.py", line 21, in <module>
    inRange_hsv = cv2.inRange(erode_hsv, color_dist[ball_color]['Lower'], color_dist[ball_color]['Upper'])
KeyError: ('red', 'green')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be the soultion:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


ball_color=('red','green')

color_dist = {'red': {'Lower': np.array([-10, 100, 100]), 'Upper': np.array([10, 255, 255])},
             'green': {'Lower': np.array([35, 43, 35]), 'Upper': np.array([90, 255, 255])},
             }

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('camera', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        if frame is not None:
            gs_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)                     # 高斯模糊
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(gs_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)                 # 转化成HSV图像
            erode_hsv = cv2.erode(hsv, None, iterations=2)                   # 腐蚀 粗的变细
            b_shape = hsv.shape[0], hsv.shape[1], 1
            inRange_hsv = np.zeros(b_shape, hsv.dtype)
            for i in ball_color:
                inRange_hsv_tmp = cv2.inRange(erode_hsv, color_dist[i]['Lower'], color_dist[i]['Upper'])
                inRange_hsv = cv2.bitwise_or(inRange_hsv, inRange_hsv_tmp)
            cnts = cv2.findContours(inRange_hsv.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

            if len(cnts) > 0:
                c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
                rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
                box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
                cv2.drawContours(frame, [np.int0(box)], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
    
            cv2.imshow('camera', frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        else:
            print("無畫面")
    else:
        print("無法讀取鏡頭！")

cap.release()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You tried to pass tuple of strings as argument to `cv2.inRange` and it could work with tuple length 1, but it won't work with more arguments. So you should iterate them and use `cv2.inRange` for every color separately and then use `cv2.bitwise_or` for them to 'concat' binary images.
And about `cnts`: sometimes it could not find any contours so you should use `if` statement to control it.
Edit: in this line `inRange_hsv = cv2.bitwise_or(inRange_hsv, inRange_hsv_tmp)`

Comment: Hello! Thanks alot for your help.
I tried pasting your code into my program and there were no errors, but the camera is unable to detect any colours.

Comment: there is one thing in your code ```'Lower': np.array([-10, 100, 100])``` are you sure that -10 value is possible in opencv`s color spaces?

Comment: sorry, I made a small mistake, please check the changes in my answer

Comment: Omg thanks a lot, it works now. You’re a lifesaver!!! Thank you!